# Swift ios how to change font , font color when tap and uptate , and some other properties in a segment control

Tags: ios, swift, segment

I wanted to design tabs using segment control but the thing that i know regarding all its properties is just limited for now. the first image is my current one the 2nd image is what i want to achieve
[image: my current output]
[image]

What i really want to achieved is the segment control which has items all , pending , expired , finished. does anyone has an idea how to achieve distance between items in segments , also change the font color and style according to the design sample below. Thank You.

what i have so far.

```
let appearance = SMSegmentAppearance()
            appearance.segmentOnSelectionColour =  UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.8706, blue: 0.7608, alpha: 1.0)
            appearance.segmentOffSelectionColour = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.8706, blue: 0.7608, alpha: 1.0)
            appearance.titleOnSelectionFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25.0)
//            segmentControlView.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Black", size: 12)
            appearance.titleOffSelectionFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25.0)
            appearance.contentVerticalMargin = 10

            /*
             Init SMsegmentView
             Set divider colour and width here if there is a need
             */
            let segmentFrame = CGRect(x: self.margin, y: 5, width: self.segmentControlView.frame.size.width - self.margin*8, height: 50.0)
            self.segmentView = SMSegmentView(frame: segmentFrame, dividerColour: UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.8706, blue: 0.7608, alpha: 1.0), dividerWidth: 1.0, segmentAppearance: appearance)
            self.segmentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.8706, blue: 0.7608, alpha: 1.0)

            self.segmentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
            self.segmentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.8706, blue: 0.7608, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            self.segmentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0


            self.segmentView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectSegmentInSegmentView(segmentView:)), for: .valueChanged)

            self.segmentView.addSegmentWithTitle("All", onSelectionImage: UIImage(named: ""), offSelectionImage: UIImage(named: ""))

            self.segmentView.addSegmentWithTitle("Pending", onSelectionImage: UIImage(named: ""), offSelectionImage: UIImage(named: ""))

                self.segmentView.addSegmentWithTitle("Finished", onSelectionImage: UIImage(named: ""), offSelectionImage: UIImage(named: ""))

                self.segmentView.addSegmentWithTitle("Expired", onSelectionImage: UIImage(named: ""), offSelectionImage: UIImage(named: ""))

//            var ownerNames = [String]()
//
//            if  fetchedToDoItems.count > 0 {
//                for item in fetchedToDoItems {
//                    if item.houseNo == loggedInUserHouseNumber &&
//                        !ownerNames.contains(item.ownerName!) {
//                        ownerNames.append(item.ownerName!)
//                    }
//                }
//
//                for name in ownerNames {
//                    // Add segments
//                    self.segmentView.addSegmentWithTitle(name, onSelectionImage: UIImage(named: ""), offSelectionImage: UIImage(named: ""))
//                }
//
//            }

            // Set segment with index 0 as selected by default
            self.segmentView.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
            self.segmentControlView.addSubview(self.segmentView)
```

Comment: which one is your Segment control

Comment: the label all , pending , finished are segments Sir

Comment: the segment titles

Comment: So what you want, You want to change the text colour of what.?

Comment: i want to implement the design og the second image , i have my current outout which is the first image , i only want to implement on how all , pending , finished , expired looks at the 2nd picture

Comment: dont worry about the chore contents , just the segments all , pending finished etc.

Comment: Have you done it programmatically.? I mean added the segmented controller manually or programmatically.?

Comment: its programmatically added Sir

Comment: my code is above jsut tell me if there is lacking

Comment: https://github.com/subinspathilettu/SJSegmentedViewController, I would suggest you to work with this, instead of the native as it is much more similar to your requirement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169056/discussion-between-abhirajsinh-thakore-and-durn-kurvirck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i have Seen the documentation:

You just need to change the Font style and size:

You can try :

**Step:1 Print fonts**

```
func printFonts() {
    let fontFamilyNames = UIFont.familyNames
    for familyName in fontFamilyNames {
        print("------------------------------")
        print("Font Family Name = [\(familyName)]")
        let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName)
        print("Font Names = [\(names)]")
    }
}
```

**Step :2 Set it to appearance:-**

```
appearance.titleOnSelectionFont = UIFont(name: "TradeGothicLTStd-Cn18", size: 10.0)!
appearance.titleOffSelectionFont = UIFont(name: "TradeGothicLTStd-Cn18", size: 10.0)!
```

Hope this help!

### Edit to set Selected to Black and Unselected to White

```
appearance.segmentOffSelectionColour = UIColor.white //UnSelected Colour
appearance.segmentOnSelectionColour = UIColor.black //Selected Colour
```

Comment: Edited the Answer to change the selected and non selected colour in tab bar.